# QWebSocketServer and connect from Safari

Tags: javascript, qt, websocket, safari

i make test echo server in QT ..same as example http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebsockets-echoserver-example.html

in Chrome, Firefox, Opera connect correct without problems...

only in Safari when i want connect to server, so no connection is created and trycreated websocket is disconnected..

any help what i doing wrong? Or any setting in safari which i have disabled or???

thanks for any help